# Qn on Drools Flow: How to specify a ruleflow to start at specific node?

Tags: drools, drools-flow

I'm working on a Drools project which requires pausing of ruleflow (write into database) and resuming the ruleflow (read from database). I know that Drools provides out of the box JPA/transaction style persistence, one I couldn't get it running and second it persists in serialized form, not very useful for my use cases.

What I come up with is for my system to remember the node where the ruleflow is paused (can be done), persist the node id and working facts in database (can be done). Then retrieve these persisted data when resuming the ruleflow, inject them into the knowledge session (can be done) and continue the ruleflow from the paused node (cannot be done). But I have yet to find a way to start processing from a specific node.

Please help, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having a similar issue  (if I understood your question), as far as I know, drools allows only 1 start node per ruleflow,  so the only chance I see to start a ruleflow at an arbitrary node is to start right into a gateway (diverge) node, the gateway node should be connected to every node in the ruleflow (or as much as you neeed), the rules defined for it should allow you to start the workflow at any node. Sure this work arround is not pretty but might be enough.

By the way, If you find a better solution please let me know.

Fuanka